Can I trade with my friend on PC if I'm on Xbox?
I haven't tried yet, but I'd like to see if anybody knows: can I trade in Warframe with my friend on PC if I'm on Xbox?

Warframe's official site states:

Yes, you are able to trade with players on different platforms (depending on those players’ Cross Platform settings). Trading will function the same as gifting, except for trading Platinum between Nintendo Switch and other platforms, which is not available.

Only the Nintendo Switch has some limitations, but for your scenario, the answer is yes.  The console player will need to have a Cross Platform Save Account according to the site as well (also explained in this answer:

To make sure you can trade with friends or fellow Tenno across platforms, make sure you are using a Cross Platform Save Account (or PC account*) and have Cross Platform Play enabled via your in-game settings. TennoGuard 2FA is required to trade in-game items with fellow Tenno in Warframe, which can be enabled via the Account Management page.

